# Mocking net.sf.ehcache.Cache (ehcache) with .put method stub (Mockito)

Tags: java, mocking, ehcache, mockito

I'm developing a simple cache functionality with EhCache.
There is a generic base class that implements my cache interface (BECache):

```
public class EhCacheBase<K, V> implements BECache<K, V> {

private static CacheManager cacheManager;
private String cacheName;

public EhCacheBase(String cacheName) {
    this.cacheName = cacheName;
}

public void cache(K key, V value) {
    Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
    if (cache == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Failed to obtain cache: " + cacheName);
    }
    Element element = new Element(key, value);
    cache.put(element);
}
```

The purpose is to have caches defined as follows:

```
public class ObjectCache extends EhCacheBase<String, Object>{

    public ObjectCache (String cacheName) {
       super(cacheName);
    }
}
```

assuming 'cacheName' is defined in ehcache.xml I get a nice class for
caching certain objects.

I'm trying to write a test for the 'EhCacheBase.cache(...)' method that ensures
a cache is retrieved and a value is put (using Mockito):

```
private static final String CACHE_NAME = "testCache";
@Mock
private CacheManager cacheManager;
@Mock
private Cache cache;
private EhCacheBase<String, Object> ehCacheBase;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    ehCacheBase = new EhCacheBase<String, Object>(CACHE_NAME);
    EhCacheBase.setCacheManager(cacheManager);
}

@Test
public void shouldRetrieveCacheAndPutOneValueInIt() {
    //given
    Object o = new Object();
    when(cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME)).thenReturn(cache);

    //when
    ehCacheBase.cache("KEY", o);

    //then
    verify(cacheManager, times(1)).getCache(CACHE_NAME);
    verify(cache, times(1)).put(any(Element.class));
}
```

When I run the test I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2731)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1440)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1417)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1382)
    at org.fxoo.bookingengine.dao.dataproviders.caches.EhCacheBase.cache(EhCacheBase.java:24)
    at org.fxoo.bookingengine.dao.dataproviders.caches.EhCacheBaseTest.shouldCacheOneValue(EhCacheBaseTest.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

It seems like the 'put' method in 'cache' mock is calling some others methods.
But as you can read in Mockito docs:

Use doNothing() for setting void methods to do nothing. Beware that void methods on mocks do nothing by default! 
However, there are rare situations when doNothing() comes handy:

By the way, I tried: doNothing().when(cache).put(any(Element.class));
and it didn't help either.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Because put(Element) is final, mocking it is an issue.

Comment: The same happens with `get(stringName)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cache.put is final, so you need to use [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) if you want to mock it.

Your test would look like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Cache.class)
public class EhCacheBaseTest {
    private static final String CACHE_NAME = "testCache";
    private CacheManager cacheManager;
    private Cache cache;
    private EhCacheBase<String, Object> ehCacheBase;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        // You can statically import mock method, but left it this way 
        // for clarity
        cacheManager = PowerMockito.mock(CacheManager.class);
        cache = PowerMockito.mock(Cache.class);
        ehCacheBase = new EhCacheBase<String, Object>(CACHE_NAME);
        EhCacheBase.setCacheManager(cacheManager);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRetrieveCacheAndPutOneValueInIt() {
        //given
        Object o = new Object();
        when(cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME)).thenReturn(cache);

        //when
        ehCacheBase.cache("KEY", o);

        //then
        verify(cacheManager, times(1)).getCache(CACHE_NAME);
        verify(cache, times(1)).put(any(Element.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I posted a similar question to Mockito Google Group ([here](http://groups.google.com/group/mockito/browse_thread/thread/a2c232e35d757dfb)). I got a quick response from Eric Lefevre-Ardant that explained everything. The net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put method is final so it cannot be stubbed - Mockito fails to provide its own implementation.

Comment: If it's final, you could mock it with PowerMock, an extension to Mockito.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of Mockito (1.10.19) is [not supported by PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13).

Instead of using PowerMock, if possible another solution is to code to the `net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache` interface instead of the `net.sf.ehcache.Cache` implementation.

The Ehcache interface can easily be mocked with standard Mockito.

I've adapted the accepted answer's example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EhCacheBaseTest {
    private static final String CACHE_NAME = "testCache";

    @Mock private Ehcache cache;
    @Mock private CacheManager cacheManager;

    private EhCacheBase<String, Object> ehCacheBase;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        ehCacheBase = new EhCacheBase<String, Object>(CACHE_NAME);
        EhCacheBase.setCacheManager(cacheManager);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRetrieveCacheAndPutOneValueInIt() {
        //given
        Object o = new Object();
        when(cacheManager.getEhcache(CACHE_NAME)).thenReturn(cache);

        //when
        ehCacheBase.cache("KEY", o);

        //then
        verify(cacheManager, times(1)).getEhcache(CACHE_NAME);
        verify(cache, times(1)).put(any(Element.class));
    }
}
```